# C# Load Value from .txt file to NumericUpDown?

Tags: c#, text, numericupdown

I'm looking to load a value contained in a .txt file into a numeric up-down. I've been loading text from .txts into combo boxes using this:

```
//Load Movelist
        if (comboBox_PlayerChar.SelectedIndex == 27 && gameno == 3)
        {

            charno = 27;

            this.comboBox_Movelist.Items.Clear();

            StreamReader movelist = new StreamReader(@"filepath\document.txt");
            string line = movelist.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                comboBox_Movelist.Items.Add(line);
                line = movelist.ReadLine();
            }

         }
```

I'd imagine it'd be a similar method for numericUpDowns, but I'm honestly clueless as of what to do. I've done some snooping around the internet and no one else seems to want to do the same.

tl;dr, I need *some* way to take a single number that's in a text file, write it to a variable and set the numericUpDown to that variable.

The important part is getting the value into a variable. setting the actual numericUpDown is easy.

Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Comment: are you familiar with the`Split()` function.. why not use linq to read the file and spilt the values into a `List<T>` then bind the List<T> to the combobox..? can you show what 1 line of the text file looks like.. are there any special delimiters `, Tab, etc`

Comment: That's is a valid suggestion but it don't think it is what the OP is looking to solve. He can't get a number read in a text file into a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a single number value in a text file

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"filepath\document.txt"))
{    
    // read the first line
    string line = sr.ReadLine();

    // parse the line for an integer
    int value;
    int.TryParse(line, out value);

    // if the line in the file was indeed an integer, the variable value will be equal to it now

    // sr will be disposed at end of using block
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `Dispose` the `StreamReader` (ideally by using a `using`-Block)

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
while(!movelist.EndOfStream)
{
    comboBox_Movelist.Items.Add(line);
    line = movelist.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You should explain the code you post.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the OP is looking for, this is just the OP's code refactored

Comment: EndOfStream is the end of file. it is not null.